# Want to concat two XML elements in PL/SQL, want to concat two XMLTYPE elements

Tags: xml, plsql

```
declare
var1 XMLTYPE;
var2 XMLTYPE;
var3 XMLTYPE;
var4 XMLTYPE;
Begin
var1 := XMLTYPE('<START>') ;
var2 := XMLTYPE('<DOCUMENT><TITLE>Mr.</TITLE>');
var3 := XMLTYPE('<NAME>Mr.</NAME></DOCUMENT>');
var4 := XMLTYPE('</START>') ;
end;
```

How can I concatenate the above XMLTYPE variables ?

thank you.

Comment: I also want to know how to convert a varchar2 into XMLTYPE and a XMLTYPE into varchar2 ..

the above variable will give error since the XMLTYPE variable should have starting and ending tag and well formed.

Comment: You can't 'concatenate' XML as it doesn't make sense to.  If `A` and `B` were two well-formed XML documents, then "`A || B`" would itself not be well-formed as it would have two root elements.  Why do you think you need to be able to concatenate XML documents this way?

Answer (score 1):

Your example will not compile as none of the strings are valid XML documents. (You will get ORA-31011: XML Parsing Failed).

You could put each fragment in a VARCHAR2 and then concatenate those in the XMLTYPE function:

```
declare
    var1 varchar2(32);
    var2 varchar2(32);
    var3 varchar2(32);
    var4 varchar2(32);
    varx xmltype;
Begin
    var1 := '<START>';
    var2 := '<DOCUMENT><TITLE>Mr.</TITLE>';
    var3 := '<NAME>Mr.</NAME></DOCUMENT>';
    var4 := '</START>' ;

    varx := xmltype(var1 || var2 || var3 || var4);

    dbms_output.put_line(varx.getStringVal());    
end;
```

As you can see from the last line, the method 'getStringVal()' will return the varchar2 value of the XML.